# Is there any merge tool for Macbook Air M2?

Tags: version-control, atlassian-sourcetree, mergetool, version-control-migration

I recently switched to a MacBook Air M2 for my development work and have been using SourceTree as my Git client. However, I've encountered an issue as my previous merge tool, DiffMerge, is not compatible with the M2 architecture.

I'm now looking for **recommendations for a merge tool that is compatible with MacBook Air M2** and can seamlessly integrate with SourceTree for my development workflow.
Alternatively, if there are **any workarounds or configurations I can implement to make DiffMerge compatible with my MacBook Air M2,** I would greatly appreciate any guidance on that as well.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!

In my attempts to address this issue, I first searched online for any updates or compatibility patches for DiffMerge that would make it compatible with the MacBook Air M2 architecture. However, I couldn't find any relevant information or solutions.

Next, I explored alternative merge tools available for macOS and tried installing a few, but none of them seemed to seamlessly integrate with SourceTree or provide the functionality I was accustomed to with DiffMerge.

Ideally, **I was hoping to find either a compatible merge tool for MacBook Air M2 that integrates well with SourceTree, or a workaround to make DiffMerge function properly on my new machine.**

Comment: Kdiff3, p4merge - in theory meld should work from homebrew but it's not working for me. I'm personally using p4merge. It's completely free and separate from Perforce but you may need to click around their website to get to it